# How to push logout a user or refresh user page in spring/stomp websocket

Tags: spring-boot, stomp

I'm new to Spring and this maybe a basic task but after I've set up spring boot with stomp websocket, an interactive web page is accomplished and I can push a json object to a client webpage but my goal is to refresh the client/user's page only, I don't need a json transfer.
I just want to refresh the user's page after admin has logged him out.

this is my `app.js`

```
    var stompClient = null;

    function setConnected(connected) {
        $("#connect").prop("disabled", connected);
        $("#disconnect").prop("disabled", !connected);

        if (connected) {
            $("#conversation").show();
        } else {
            $("#conversation").hide();
        }
        $("#greetings").html("");
    }

    function connect() {
        var socket = new SockJS('/vira-websocket');
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
            setConnected(true);
            stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function (greeting) {
                showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
            });
        });
    }
    function disconnect() {
        if (stompClient !== null) {
            stompClient.disconnect();
        }
        setConnected(false);
    }
    function sendName() {
        stompClient.send("/app/hello", {}, JSON.stringify({'name': $("#name").val()}));
    }

    $(function () {
        $( "form" ).on('submit', function (e) {e.preventDefault();});
        $( "#connect" ).click(function() { connect(); });
        $( "#disconnect" ).click(function() { disconnect(); });
        $( "#send" ).click(function() { sendName(); });
    });
```

my config

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
    public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
        @Override
        public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
            config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
            config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        }
        @Override
        public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
            registry.addEndpoint("/vira-websocket").withSockJS();
        }
    }
```

and controller

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {
    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(3000); // simulated delay
        return new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share your `WebSocketConfig` and the controller in which your `@MessageMapping`
    `@SendTo` are set

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question but if you want to refresh the page instead of pushing a json just replace `location.reload();` with the callback of `subscribe` function which is the second argument.

```
function connect() {
        var socket = new SockJS('/vira-websocket');
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
            setConnected(true);
            stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', location.reload());
        });
    }
```

> [according to the documentation](http://jmesnil.net/stomp-websocket/doc/) The client will send a STOMP
>   SUBSCRIBE frame to the server and register the callback. Every time
>   the server send a message to the client, the client will in turn call
>   the callback with a STOMP Frame object corresponding to the message:

which means your refresh will be called after you sent a push to the subscribed users.